# What do I do with translated .Resx files for localization?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, localization

I am adding multi-language capabilities to my application, and I added all the text strings into the main english resource file, and then translated them into different languages. I now have about 8 folders with the name in this format "de-DE" and inside is the resource files for the corresponding language. Now that these are translated..What exactly do I do with them? How do I add them to my project so I can have different variations of my project, or have the user be able to switch languages? Thanks alot I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a "Resources.xx.resx" file for each language "xx" and add them to your project. They will be compiled into `YourAppName.resources.dll` files in directories for each language. The .NET resource system will pick them up automatically based on the current UI culture (`Thread.CurrentUICulture`).

Comment: Okay. So when you say the .net resource system will pick them up automatically does that mean I don't have to add any code in the application for the user to switch languages? Or does it automatically change languages based on the users systems language? So aslong as the resource files are added it should change the language dependant on the user? Or do I need to add some kind of currentuiculture code?

Comment: It's based on the current value of "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture". If you want to take this offline and email me at support@hexadigm.com, I can send you a longer explanation. It's was already pre-written (for a customer of mine) but because there are a couple of references to my own commercial localization app (nothing promotional though - it answers what you're asking), I don't want to post it here in case it gets red-flagged as inappropriate.

Comment: @user1632018, if you just want your app to use the system's language, you don't have any code to write. If you want the user to be able to change the language, you need to change the CurrentUICulture manually.